# Structure for efficient insert and query: where X = 1 and Y = 2 and C = 3 ... and N = M

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I'm looking for a structure that will allow me to perform a query as described in the title. The maximum value of N is around 20.

The structure will store approximately 1000 pre-known elements. Each of these elements has a certain attribute, and each attribute can have 1-20 different values. For example:

`Element1 = [attribute1: ["w1,"w2","w3"], attribute2: ["x1,"x2"]]`

Then, I would like to search for an element (knowing in advance that at most one will match) that satisfies the requirement `attribute1.contains("w3") AND attribute2.contains("x1")`.

The structure, once filled with elements, remains unchanged over time. It can have a higher insert complexity, such as `O(n^2)`. However, I would like the search operation to have a complexity of, let's say, `O(N*logN)` if possible.Where `N` is number of elements.

Approaches I have tried:

1. Separate index for each attribute `(HashMap<Attribute, Set<Element>>)` and then intersecting the sets - this approach has the problem that I already know that most elements will satisfy all conditions except one. In other words, each set intersection does not reduce the subsequent ones.

Insert = `O(k)`, where `k` is the number of attributes (very good)

Search = `O(k * n)`, where `k` is the number of attributes, and `n` is the number of elements - in the worst case, it requires `n-1` set intersections.

2. Trie - Building a tree with attribute values in the appropriate order.

Insert = `O(k^n)`, where `n` is the number of attributes, and `k` is the average number of attribute values.

Search = `O(k)`, where `k` is the number of attributes (very good), but the insert complexity (+ memory usage) is too high.

3. AVL / RBL - they do not allow for multi-dimensional queries.
4. kd-tree - This would be a suitable structure if it weren't for the fact that in my case, there will only be 1-20 different attributes to partition by. Most of the time, the number of elements will be high (~1000), but they will only contain 3 attributes, which makes it impossible to build a balanced tree.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: How many attributes are there? That is, the examples you show have 2 attributes: `attribute1` and `attribute2`. What is the average number of values that each attribute list will contain? Are there any restrictions on the queries (for example, are `or`, `xor`, and `not` allowed? Is there a `notContains()`? Can the queries be arbitrarily complex? Are some queries much more common than others, making caching of results a meaningful optimization? How often are updates made?

Comment: @JimMischel Up to 20 attributes. Average values for each attribute is 10. No, there will be only one query with `contains`. Updates are never made. I re-build the structure every 30 minutes, and then I perform single query which looks like this: `where attribute1.contains("x") and attribute2.contains("y") and attribute3.contains("p")....`
Ofc every query will have different `contains` parameters. Each query always queries for all attributes.

Comment: What is exactly the problem with a 20-dimensional kd-tree? kd-trees do not need to be (perfectly) balanced. Have you tried it? How "bad" was it?

Comment: @TilmannZ "Most of the time, the number of elements will be high (~1000), but they will only contain 3 attributes, which makes it impossible to build a balanced tree."

Comment: Why are you going through the exercise to build a data structure if you're only going to do one query? That is, you have to visit every element in order to build the data structure, so why not just "do the query" during that pass? That is `for each data element . . .`

Comment: @JimMischel I will perform many queries, not one. I mean "one type of query", for example:

`Query1 = find all elements where attribute1.contains("x") and attribute2.contains("y") and attributeN.contains("some value")`

`Query2 = find all elements where attribute1.contains("ASD") and attribute2.contains("QWE") and attributeN.contains("some value")`  

So all queries will always perform a query with all attributes taken into account, but with different values

Comment: I'm a bit confused, then by this: *The structure, once filled with elements, remains unchanged over time. It can have a higher insert complexity, such as O(n^2). However, I would like the search operation to have a complexity of, let's say, O(N\*logN) if possible .Where N is number of elements.* And in a comment you said, "Updates are never made." So which is it: updates or not?

Comment: @JimMischel remains unchanhed == updates are never made. so no - it's not updated. I know in advance all elements attributes. 

Currently I have very good results in approach where for every element I create a bit-set. Then during a lookup I create a mask consisting of query parameteres. And next I perform `(mask & element_bitset) == mask` - if it's true then I found a match. It takes `O(n)` in the worst case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I decided to stick with the simplest possible approach because it doesn't make much difference in my case, so I prioritize code readability (so i will stay with `Normal` implementation). For those interested, I'm leaving the results of my tests here.

I created 3 different structures. `InvertedIndex` proposed by @Jim Mischel, `BitSet` for attributes and last one called `Normal` with naive iterating over all attributes `O(n*k)` where `N` is number of elements and `k` number or query attributes.

Inverted index with intersections on search:

```java
public class InvertedIndex implements ScenarioStructure {

    Map<Rule, Set<String>> invertedIndex = new HashMap<>();

    public InvertedIndex(List<Scenario> scenarios) {
        scenarios.forEach(s -> s.getRules().forEach(rule -> invertedIndex.computeIfAbsent(rule, rule1 -> new HashSet<>()).add(s.getName())));
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<String> find(List<Rule> rules) {
        var scenarios = rules.stream().map(rule -> invertedIndex.get(rule))
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .iterator();
        return getIntersection(scenarios);
    }

    public static Collection<String> getIntersection(Iterator<Set<String>> sets) {
        if (sets == null || !sets.hasNext())
            return Collections.emptySet();

        Set<String > intersection = new HashSet<>(sets.next());
        while (sets.hasNext() && !intersection.isEmpty()) {
            intersection.retainAll(sets.next());
        }

        return intersection;
    }
```

BitSet with AND'in on search:

```java
public class BitSet implements ScenarioStructure {

    private final List<ScenarioBits> scenarioBits;
    private final int words;

    public BitSet(List<Scenario> scenarios) {
        this.scenarioBits = new ArrayList<>(scenarios.size());
        this.words = (Rule.values().length >> 3) + 1;

        scenarios.forEach(s -> {
            var bits = new long[words];
            for (Rule rule : s.getRules()) {
                var bitIndex = rule.ordinal();
                var bitWord = bitIndex >> 6;
                bits[bitWord] = bits[bitWord] | (1L << (bitIndex & (64 - 1)));
            }
            scenarioBits.add(new ScenarioBits(s.getName(), bits));

        });

    }

    @Override
    public Collection<String> find(List<Rule> rules) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(20);

        var mask = new long[words];
        for (Rule rule : rules) {
            var bitIndex = rule.ordinal();
            var bitWord = bitIndex >> 6;
            mask[bitWord] = mask[bitWord] | (1L << (bitIndex & (64 - 1)));
        }

        for (ScenarioBits scenarioBit : scenarioBits) {
            var bitSet = scenarioBit.bitSet();
            var match = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < mask.length; i++) {
                var rule = mask[i];
                if (rule != 0) {
                    match = (rule & bitSet[i]) == rule;
                    if (!match) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (match) {
                result.add(scenarioBit.name);
            }
        }
        return result;

    }
      private record ScenarioBits(String name, long[] bitSet) {
    }
```

Normal naive approach:

```java
public class Normal implements ScenarioStructure{

    private final List<Scenario> scenarios;

    public Normal(List<Scenario> scenarios) {
        this.scenarios = scenarios;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<String> find(List<Rule> rules) {
        var result = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (Scenario scenario : scenarios) {
            var match = true;
            for (Rule rule : rules) {
                if(!scenario.getRules().contains(rule)) {
                    match = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(match) {
                result.add(scenario.getName());
            }
        }
        return result;

    }
}
```

Scenario with Rules looks like this (I merged all attributes into single flat array):

```java
public class Scenario {
    private final String name;
    private final Set<Rule> rules;
   // constructor, getters, hashcode
}
public enum Rule {
    A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, A8, A9, A10, A11, A12, A13, A14, A15, A16, A17, A18, A19, A20,
    B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6, B7, B8, B9, B10, B11, B12, B13, B14, B15, B16, B17, B18, B19, B20,
    C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8, C9, C10, C11, C12, C13, C14, C15, C16, C17, C18, C19, C20,
    D1, D2, D3, D4, D5, D6, D7, D8, D9, D10, D11, D12, D13, D14, D15, D16, D17, D18, D19, D20,
    E1, E2, E3, E4, E5, E6, E7, E8, E9, E10, E11, E12, E13, E14, E15, E16, E17, E18, E19, E20,
    F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7, F8, F9, F10, F11, F12, F13, F14, F15, F16, F17, F18, F19, F20,
    G1, G2, G3, G4, G5, G6, G7, G8, G9, G10, G11, G12, G13, G14, G15, G16, G17, G18, G19, G20,
    H1, H2, H3, H4, H5, H6, H7, H8, H9, H10, H11, H12, H13, H14, H15, H16, H17, H18, H19, H20,
    I1, I2, I3, I4, I5, I6, I7, I8, I9, I10, I11, I12, I13, I14, I15, I16, I17, I18, I19, I20,
    J1, J2, J3, J4, J5, J6, J7, J8, J9, J10, J11, J12, J13, J14, J15, J16, J17, J18, J19, J20,
    K1, K2, K3, K4, K5, K6, K7, K8, K9, K10, K11, K12, K13, K14, K15, K16, K17, K18, K19, K20,
    L1, L2, L3, L4, L5, L6, L7, L8, L9, L10, L11, L12, L13, L14, L15, L16, L17, L18, L19, L20,
    M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8, M9, M10, M11, M12, M13, M14, M15, M16, M17, M18, M19, M20,
    N1, N2, N3, N4, N5, N6, N7, N8, N9, N10, N11, N12, N13, N14, N15, N16, N17, N18, N19, N20,
    O1, O2, O3, O4, O5, O6, O7, O8, O9, O10, O11, O12, O13, O14, O15, O16, O17, O18, O19, O20,
    P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7, P8, P9, P10, P11, P12, P13, P14, P15, P16, P17, P18, P19, P20,
    R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R7, R8, R9, R10, R11, R12, R13, R14, R15, R16, R17, R18, R19, R20,
    S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6, S7, S8, S9, S10, S11, S12, S13, S14, S15, S16, S17, S18, S19, S20,
    T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19, T20,
    U1, U2, U3, U4, U5, U6, U7, U8, U9, U10, U11, U12, U13, U14, U15, U16, U17, U18, U19, U20,
    W1, W2, W3, W4, W5, W6, W7, W8, W9, W10, W11, W12, W13, W14, W15, W16, W17, W18, W19, W20,
}
```

Then I'm doing simple (also naive but good enough) benchmark where I create `N` random scenarios - each scenario has random number of rules (200 on average) and perform a query with 20 attributes.

```java
  List<Scenario> generate = ScenariosGenerator.generate(100);

        var start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        var inverted = new InvertedIndex(generate);
        System.out.println("Inverted creation: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        var normal = new Normal(generate);
        System.out.println("Normal creation: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        var bloom = new BitSet(generate);
        System.out.println("BitSet creation: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));

        var rules = List.of(Rule.A1, Rule.B2, Rule.C3, Rule.D4, Rule.E1, Rule.F1, Rule.G3, Rule.H1, Rule.I1, Rule.J1, Rule.K6,
                Rule.L1, Rule.M6, Rule.N6, Rule.O6, Rule.P6, Rule.R6, Rule.S2, Rule.T6, Rule.W6);

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Collection<String> scenarios1 = inverted.find(rules);
        System.out.println("Inverted find: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Collection<String> scenarios2 = bloom.find(rules);
        System.out.println("bitset find: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Collection<String> scenarios3 = normal.find(rules);
        System.out.println("normal find: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
```

For 1000 scenarios it printlns:

```
Inverted creation ms: 36
Normal creation ms: 0
BitSet creation ms: 9

Inverted find ms: 3
bitset find ms: 0
normal find ms: 1
```

for 10 000:

```
Inverted creation ms: 266
Normal creation ms: 0
BitSet creation ms: 80

Inverted find ms: 5
bitset find ms: 2
normal find ms: 6
```

for 100 000:

```
Inverted creation ms: 3975
Normal creation ms: 1
BitSet creation ms: 631

Inverted find ms: 39
bitset find ms: 11
normal find ms: 41
```

for 300 000:

```
Inverted creation ms: 11415
Normal creation ms: 0
BitSet creation ms: 1421
Inverted find ms: 90
bitset find ms: 16
normal find ms: 85
```

for 400 000:
`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

To summarize:

`InvertedIndex` takes too much memory, about 8GB for 400k Scenarios. It also performs the worst, it takes the most memory, the most time to build itself and close to `Normal` on `find()`.

`Normal` performs much better than I expected when it comes to `find()`. It takes a linear memory (about 1.4GB for 400k Scenarios).

`BitSet` has the best `find()` performance, it's created really quick and 400k elements takes only 160 MB.

Also `BitSet` and `Normal` has the advantage over the `InvertedIndex` that, they don't have to check all elements for `contains()` query, we can just stop iterating on first matching element, for `InvertedIndex` I need to intersect all of them.

The benchmark is not entirely representative, but I just wanted to compare the orders of magnitude. Most of the RAM memory is occupied because of `HashMap$Node` objects.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned in the original post that you have tried a `(HashMap<Attribute, Set<Element>>)`, and then intersect the sets. But that whereas this works you end up intersecting `k` sets (where `k` is the number of conditions) that contain `n` (approximately 1000 elements).

You have 20 attributes and up to 20 possible values for each attribute. How about creating a hash map in which the key is a string consisting of the attribute name and the value, and the value would be a `Set<element>`. You hash map would then have approximately 400 keys, but the sets would be much smaller. For example, if you have:

```
Element1 = [attribute1: ["w1,"w2","w3"], attribute2: ["x1,"x2"]]
Element2 = [attribute1: ["w1","w3","w4"], attribute2: ["x2","x3"]]
Element3 = [attribute1: ["w3","w4","w5"], attribute2: ["x1","x3"]]
```

Then your hash map would contain:

```
["a1:w1", [element1, element2]]
["a1:w2", [element1]]
["a1:w3", [element1, element2, element3]]
["a1:w4", [element2, element3]]
["a1:w5", [element3]]
["a2:x1", [element1, element3]]
["a2:x2", [element1, element2]]
["a2:x3", [element2, element3]]
```

With 400 keys, it's likely that the resulting sets of elements that you have to intersect will be much smaller.

This approach would require more memory than your `(HashMap<Attribute, Set<Element>>)`, but the resulting sets that you have to intersect would be much smaller.

The bitset idea is kind of interesting. Linear search of 1000 elements looking for a mask is pretty dang quick. Although you do have to examine all 1000 elements, it might be faster than the hash map idea I presented simply because the overhead of setting up multiple set intersections could very well be more expensive than a simple linear search. That's something you'd have to determine empirically.